# order unique accounts by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table:

```
create table remote (account int ,datecreated datetime,status int)
insert into remote (account , datecreated,status)
values

(123,'2015-08-25',1),
(123,'2015-08-25',1),
(123,'2015-09-26',1),
(1238,'2015-08-25',1),

(123,'2014-08-25',1),
(123,'2014-08-26',1),
(1238,'2014-08-25',1),
(1238,'2014-08-25',1),
(1235,'2014-08-25',1),

(1234,'2014-09-22',1),
(1234,'2014-09-22',1),

(1234,'2014-10-29',1),
(1236,'2014-10-25',1);
```

From here I would like to get the unique account count for each month/year where status=1
For example using the data above:

the output would be

```
count | month
-------------
1      |9/2015
2      |8/2015
2      |10/2014 
1      |9/2014
3      |8/2014
```

How can I make this work?

I use sql 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Group by `month` and `year` of `datecreated` to skip day part in count. use the same month and year in `order by` desc . Then Concatenate the month and year to get the result

```
SELECT [Count],
       [Mon/Year]= CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), [Month]) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), [year])
FROM  (SELECT [year]=Year(datecreated),
              [month]= Month(datecreated),
              [Count]= Count(distinct account)
       FROM   remote
       GROUP  BY Year(datecreated),
                 Month(datecreated)) a
ORDER  BY [year] DESC,[Month] DESC
```

**Result**

```
Count   Mon/Year
-----   --------
1       9/2015
3       8/2015
2       10/2014
1       9/2014
5       8/2014
```

Comment: from the above data there should only be 1  9/2014
since it has the same account number, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f5db/1

Answer (score 0):

This is a `group by` query with a filter and some datetime logic:

```
select year(datecreated) as yr, month(datecreated) as mon, count(*)
from remote
where status = 1
group by year(datecreated), month(datecreated)
order by yr desc, mon desc;
```

This puts the year and month into separate columns.  You can concatenate them together into a single value if you really want to.